# Storing images in Realm database in react native

Tags: android, react-native

```
let realm ;
let image;
export default class Home extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {

  ImageSource: null,
  data: null,
  Image_TAG: '',

}

realm = new Realm({
  schema: [{name: 'fields',
  properties:
  {
    id: {type: 'int',   default: 0},
    path: 'string',
    tag : 'string',
    data : 'string'
  }}], schemaVersion: 0
});

   }

  selectPhotoTapped() {
 const options = {
   quality: 1.0,
   maxWidth: 500,
   maxHeight: 500,
   storageOptions: {
     skipBackup: true
   }
 };

 ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
   console.log('Response = ', response);

   if (response.didCancel) {
     console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
   }
   else if (response.error) {
     console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
   }
   else if (response.customButton) {
     console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
   }
   else {
     let source = { uri: response.uri };

     this.setState({

       ImageSource: source,
       data: response.data

     });
   }
 });
   }

  checkNet = () => {
    NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
             if(isConnected)
             {
                 this.uploadImageToServer();
             }
             else{
               this.uploadImageToDatabase();
             }
  })
      }

  uploadImageToDatabase= () => {

ImgToBase64.getBase64String(this.state.data).then(base64String =>
  //doSomethingWith(base64String))
  {image = base64String})
  .catch(err =>{}
  );
  realm.write(() => {

  var ID = realm.objects('fields').length + 1;

   realm.create('fields', {
     id: ID,
     path: this.state.ImageSource,
     tag: this.state.Image_TAG,
     data: image,
    });

});

   }

   uploadImageToServer = () => {

 RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', 'http://192.168.0.76/survey/upload_image.php', {
   Authorization: "Bearer access-token",
   otherHeader: "foo",
   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
 }, [
     { name: 'image', filename: 'image.png', type: 'image/png', data: this.state.data },
     { name: 'image_tag', data: this.state.Image_TAG }
   ]).then((resp) => {

     var tempMSG = resp.data;

     tempMSG = tempMSG.replace(/^"|"$/g, '');

     //Alert.alert(tempMSG);
     this.state.response = resp.data;

   }).catch((err) => {
     // ...
     Alert.alert("Some Error occured;");
   })

   }

   _send(){
    this.props.navigation.navigate("ViewScreen")
  }
   _next(){
    this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeScreen")
  }


  render() {
    return (
  <View style={styles.container}>

  <ScrollView>

  <Button
  onPress={this._send.bind(this)}
  title="View all results"
  color="green"
  />

  <Button
  onPress={this._next.bind(this)}
  title="Next"
  color="#841584"/>

  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.selectPhotoTapped.bind(this)}>

      <View style={styles.ImageContainer}>

        {this.state.ImageSource === null ? <Text>Select a Photo</Text> :
          <Image style={styles.ImageContainer} source= 
   {this.state.ImageSource} />
        }

      </View>

    </TouchableOpacity>


    <TextInput

      placeholder="Enter Image Name "

      onChangeText={data => this.setState({ Image_TAG: data })}

      underlineColorAndroid='transparent'

      style={styles.TextInputStyle}
    />


    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.checkNet.bind(this)} activeOpacity={0.6} style={styles.button} >

      <Text style={styles.TextStyle}> UPLOAD IMAGE TO SERVER </Text>

    </TouchableOpacity>

    </ScrollView>
</View>


    );
  }
}
```

Above Code is Home.js file.

```
 export default class ViewImages extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data :""
    }
  }
  componentWillMount() {
      let realm = new Realm();
      let result = realm.objects('fields');
      this.state.data = result;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      <ScrollView>
       <Text style= 
{{backgroundColor:'green',fontSize:20}}>WElllllllllllllcome to view</Text>
  <FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    renderItem={({item}) =>


    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row' ,marginBottom:10,borderWidth: 1,borderColor: 'black', padding:10,marginLeft:5,marginRight:5}}>
        <Image source={{ uri: `data:image/png;base64,${item.data}`}} style={{height:35, width:32,justifyContent:'flex-start',marginRight:20,marginLeft:20}} />
        <Text style={{fontFamily: 'Verdana',fontSize: 20,justifyContent: 'center',marginLeft:20,marginRight:20,fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{item.tag}</Text>

    </View>
    }
    keyExtractor={item => item.name}
  />
  </ScrollView>
  </View>
);
  }
}
```

And above code is viewscreen.js file
What i am trying to do is upload an image based on internet.Means if device is connected to internet then it will directly upload to server and if not then it will store image tag source and base64 of image in realm databse.When i clicked on view result to see all uploaded images from realm database then it doesnt show any.What i am doing wrong here ?Does my code inserts image data in realm or not ?

Answer (score 0):

One issue i can see is `state` update

```
componentWillMount() {
  let realm = new Realm();
  let result = realm.objects('fields');
  this.state.data = result;
}
```

You have updated value in state, but it will not rerender your componen. You need to either update state like,

```
this.setState({ data:result })
```

Or

```
this.state.data = result;
this.setState({})
```

I will prefer first method to update `state`

Comment: i changed it but problem remains

Comment: In that case you need to debug it, try to print each item whether you are getting any data or not, also try by using `extraData = {this.state}` in `FlatList`

Comment: how can i check that images are inserted in realm db or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes ! I got it, response.data in imagepicker returns base encoded64 version of image and we can directly write it to database means i dont need to change to base64 version using other library.

Answer (score 0):

For people considering storing large files, like images or videos, in Realm I would suggest reading the official documentation: https://docs.realm.io/sync/using-synced-realms/syncing-data#syncing-large-objects-photos-videos-etc
which states

> ### Syncing Large Objects (Photos, Videos, etc)
>
> While the Realm database can be used to store binary data we generally
>   do not recommend storing blob data in Realm because it can be
>   inefficient for Realm sync. The diffing algorithm for syncing changes
>   works on a field level, so if a single piece of the image changes, the
>   entire image will need to be re-synced instead of just the individual
>   bits that changed. This same logic can be applied for large JSON blobs
>   as well which are stored as large string fields -- if a single
>   key-value changes, the entire JSON must be re-synced. Instead, if you
>   wanted to use Realm sync for transferring images, we recommend using
>   Realm sync to transfer the image to ROS and then have the Event
>   Handler react to the new image, remove the image from Realm and store
>   it in some object storage such as S3, and then simply store a
>   reference to the URL in the Realm database. If the client wants to see
>   the full image again they can pull the image from the URL via REST or
>   file access.